# Are there device-specific tricks for CloudKit subscriptions?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I'm having a great time experimenting with CloudKit, but I'm experiencing something really strange with my subscriptions.

I've got a very simple subscription set-up, and it works great on my iPhone 6 and my iPad retina mini. However, when I run the exact same code on my iPhone 5 (all running the latest version of iOS), I get duplicate subscription notifications.

I've even reset my ck/dev environment and deleted and re-installed the app on all the devices.

Here's the subscription code, which is right off the Getting Started pages:

```
func subscribe(myID: String) {
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "sender != %@", myID)
    let subscription = CKSubscription(recordType: "Message", predicate: predicate, options: CKSubscriptionOptions.FiresOnRecordUpdate)
    let notificationInfo = CKNotificationInfo()
    notificationInfo.alertActionLocalizationKey = "UPDATED MESSAGE!!"
    notificationInfo.shouldBadge = true
    subscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo

    self.myDatabase.saveSubscription(subscription, completionHandler: ({subscription, error in
        if let err = error {
         print("error saving subscription: \(err)")
        } else {
            print("Saved subscription")
        }
    }))
}
```

In the logs, I can see that it's the same CKRecordID that's being updated, but it's coming back with two different notification IDs.

Another thing that's interesting is that if I send the message from the simulator, there's no doubling to any device. If I send a message from the (real) iPhone 5, the iPad and iPhone 6 don't get any doubling. If I send the message from either the iPad or iPhone 6, the iPhone 5 gets the doubling.

I've also validated that there aren't repeat identical updates being pushed to the Cloud--and even if they were, the question would be why identical code running on different devices is pushing twice in one device, not on others; as it stands, I'm wondering why I'm getting doubling on the receiving end.

Anyone seen this before?

Comment: For what it's worth, I dusted off an old iPhone 4s and started testing with that, and I don't get the problem there. It's very confusing. I simply don't see why the messages are doubling on one particular device.

Comment: One thing that might make sense is if there is some reason that myID changes on that device after the first time it runs and sets up a subscription. If that happens, I could see that device sending out two different subscription requests, e.g. one for message sender != X and one for message sender != Y.

I'm not sure why it would change from X to Y, but it's certainly worth considering... I'll check that tonight.

Comment: What happened to this tread Ben? Did you find the reason?

Comment: I did not find a reason; are you seeing something similar?

The project has been on something of a pause, but one thing I did do was push the build to TestFlight, and subscriptions don't work at all in that environment. One of these days I'm going to add some UI-visible debugging and push it to TF again.

It's definitely more than a little annoying.

Comment: Hi Ben, thankfully no. But I using cloud kit which is a struggle at times trying to manage updates. Most of my problems revolve around issues with the control of the app coming back before the cloudKit has updated itself, need to write additional code around each all to confirm that call has executed. Unable to rely on completion clauses at all. As I write this, maybe there is something in it here too. You appreciate that when if says "Saved subscription" on the console, for sure it hasn't actually saved the subscription @ that point.

Comment: I haven't seen the problem with saved subscriptions not actually being saved. But interesting things can happen... I figured out what the cause of my TestFlight version was: when I promoted my schema to production, CloudKit Dashboard offered to "optimize" any "unused" indexes.  Innocently enough, I chose to let it.

It turns out that the "unused" index was for the field that drives the subscription. So it was definitely used. Once I re-added the index and deployed, it started working as before, with only the iPhone 5 doing doubles, everything else working normally.

Comment: I see that I included the code for the subscription above. It was the "sender" that was deemed to be unused. I guess I should open a radar on that because it seems like they should be able to detect that.